# reduceByKey fails for RDD with illegalAccessor error

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a working spark job written with JavaRDD. Now i  want to move the output to dataframes without making much changes to the existing code. My intention was to convert RDD to dataframes by using sqlContext. But it is deprecated so I am using SparkSession to create the SparkContext and later using it to convert RDD to dataframes.

My problem is `reduceBykey` on pair RDD doesn't work anymore. Although there is no error during compile time it fails with `IllegalAccessError` error while executing which can be traced back to the line with `reduceByKey` call in my code.

Here is the error
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.<init>()V from class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat`

Below is the code snippet

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("test")
    .master("local")
    .getOrCreate();

SparkContext sc = spark.sparkContext();
JavaRDD<String> lineInput = spark.sparkContext()
              .textFile("/tmp/test.txt", 1)
              .toJavaRDD();

JavaPairRDD<String, String> pairInput = lineInput
            .mapToPair(new FlatRDDToPairRDD());
//FlatRDDToPairRDD class takes a string and returns a Tuple
JavaPairRDD<String, String> reducedPair = pairInput.reduceByKey(new TestReducer());
JavaRDD<String> outputRDD = reducedPair.map(new 
PairRDDToFlatValueRDD());
//PairRDDToFlatValueRDD takes a Tuple and returns as string
```

This is my dependency in pom file

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Has anyone else faced similar issues ? Some hints about how to proceed will be helpful.